# Root cause for "Entity is not org-accessible" for sharing object?

Tags: apex, security, object, compile-error, access

Not able to find Sharing object for custom object **Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__Share**; giving me error while

```
List<Apttus__APTS_Agreement__share> st = new List<Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c>();
```

Comment: Is this still an open question/

Comment: @adrianLarson  it is closed.

Comment: Actually, you never accepted the answer. When an answer [addresses your problem](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), you can [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. If you have >= 15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `Sharing Settings` are set to `Public Read/Write`, then the custom object `__share` object is not available. Check the OWD Sharing by going to `Setup` > `Security Controls` > `Sharing Settings`. Once it is set to a lower level of default access, the share object should become available. Also note your code will still fail to compile, because you use `__share` on the left side of the assignment and `__c` on the right.

**Incorrect**

```
List<Apttus__APTS_Agreement__share> st = new List<Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c>();
```

**Correct**

```
List<Apttus__APTS_Agreement__share> st = new List<Apttus__APTS_Agreement__share>();
```

Comment: Sorry for that thats a typo error, I have used __Share. It has Public Read/Write access, thanks for reminder :)